# Storyboard Custom Table Header

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm still trying to figure out what is the proper way to add a custom header to a table view in Storyboards.

I know I would use this method, without using Storyboards, should I still use that?

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, even if you use ugly InterfaceBuilder-hackery to create your UI, you can still take advantage of any programmatical methods - in this case just make sure that you properly set the delegate and data source of the table view.

Comment: I thought there might be a Storyboard way to do this, guess not.